# Ruby autoloading using absolute paths

Tags: ruby, autoload

For some reason on a project I'm working someone has create a gem which does autoloading like this:

```
  [
    [:Utils, 'utils.rb'],
    [:VERSION, 'version.rb'],
    [:SomeOtherClass, 'some_other_class.rb'],
  ].each do |sym, fn|
    autoload sym, File.join(MyGem.gem_root, 'lib/my_gem', fn)
  end
```

where MyGem.gem_root gives the absolute path to the gem location, e.g. /path/to/my_gem. I am curious why this might be better (or worse) than doing something like where we rely on the gem loadpath being setup correctly:

```
 [
    [:Utils, 'utils'],
    [:VERSION, 'version'],
    [:SomeOtherClass, 'some_other_class'],
  ].each do |sym, fn|
    autoload sym, File.join(my_gem, fn)
  end
```

Personally I find it more pleasant to see this (despite the code duplication).

```
  autoload :Utils, 'my_gem/utils'
  autoload :VERSION, 'my_gem/version'
  autoload :SomeOtherClass, 'my_gem/some_other_class'
```

Anyway, which way is better if any at all?

Answer (score 0):

Much like in shell scripting, the last two blocks of code subject you to whatever capricious values are in the `PATH` environment variable. It may or may not load the correct file as a result…

Picture, for instance, a vendored gem and the `PATH` such that ruby tries to load files from the system gem prior to trying the vendored gem.

Comment: But in almost every gemspec I've seen there is a line like this:   gem.require_paths = ["lib"] which means the loadpath will be setup correctly to load using autoload :Utils, 'my_gem/utils' for example

Comment: @rainkinz: as I read `rubygems/basic_specification.rb`, it appends the gem's path to PATH instead of prepending it.